# How can I hide a light source while keeping the light?

Tags: animation, camera, eevee-render-engine, keyframes

I have made a Blender animation, but when the viewpoint is rendered I still can see the light sources and all the persons that have the same problem don't use normal lights but objects transformed into emitters.

[image: v]

Comment: Do you mean the image you posted is a render, or are you using the Rendered Shading? In case of the latter, that is normal. If you press F12, and let it render, are the sources still visible?

Comment: for an unknown reason it didn't work and the lights were visible as in the image(it is a rendered image) but when i tried after a pause , it works as intended .                                          a big thanks to MR or MS @Joachim who helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a *Viewport Render Image* instead of a *Render Image*, you'll see all the gizmos, empties, grid, and so on, unless you deactivate the *Show Overlays* option:

[image]